# Can I rename a resource in routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

In `routes.rb`, I currently have `resources :users` for the `User` controller.

A visitor can request the `User` model by `www.mydomain.com/users`

I would like to keep the User controller as it is, but have the URL request for `people` instead, such that a visitor sees the following URL: `www.mydomain.com/people`

For a single request I can do this by:

```
get '/users', to: 'users#index'
```

Is the same possible for for a resource map?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use `path` option of [`resources`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources/resources)  method:

```
resources :users, path: :people
```

Comment: Something which helps me a lot here is the `as: "x"` argument too. Using `path` creates `domain.com/people` but uses the `users` resource to build path helpers. Using `as: :people` will make path helpers read as "people" too E.G `people_path`